# Where did the old Editors' Suggestion sign of Physical Review journals come from?

Tags: journals, physics, formatting, academic-history

Physical Review journals used to indicate Editors' Suggestions with this sign:

[image: Physical Review Editors’ Suggestion icon]

In an [editorial announcement](https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.89.010001) they state that:

> The icon contains the printer’s mark that at one time appeared on the covers of all sections of the Physical Review.

I'm wondering: where did this sign come from? Does it have any meaning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks just like, well, a printer's mark, in this case, a [fleuron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography)): ❦ . I don't think there is any particular meaning besides aesthetics.

Comment: It is indeed a fleuron, specifically a floral heart *bullet*. I can't find the Unicode for an 'upright' version, but ignoring rotation these seem closer matches: ☙ ❧

Answer (score 2):

A quick search found:

Printing single vine leaves originated [around 1505](https://www.folger.edu/blogs/collation/the-single-vine-leaf-aka-the-aldine-leaf/).  It does not mean anything.  Around 1530 they were extremely popular with printers.  Printing a single vine leaf in 1530 was like printing a cat picture in 2010.